# Fetch a value using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: web page form field]

Suppose I have a webpage with some value as **three + 7 =**, as shown in the picture. How do I get the text **three + 7 =** using Selenium? I would like to print it in the console.

Comment: WebElement var= waitForElement(By.id("HtmlTagId"));

Comment: Please provide the HTML source of the picture.

Comment: it looks like captcha. if true then it shouldn't automate or no seance to automate.

Answer (score 0):

Use getAttribute. Ex If the quote is held in the attribute 'ques' of div tag.

```
String val = WebDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@name='qws']")).getAttribute("ques")
System.out.println(val);
```

Comment: ty.. getAttribute was giving me NULL value so i changed it to getText method and got the desired output.

Comment: If the text exists inside the tag getText will do. Or if it exists inside an attribute getAttribute will